# In random variables, how come we can add up the variances but not the standard deviations?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, intuition, expected-value

I was watching a video from Khan Academy and he mentioned that we can add up the variances of random variables but not their standard deviations. Can someone help me find the intuition on why?

Comment: Because if $\sf{V(X)=V(X_1)+V(X_2)}$ the statement $\sf{\sqrt{V(X)}=\sqrt{V(X_1)}+\sqrt{V(X_2)}}$ does not always hold.

Comment: Because the root of a sum is in general not the sum of the roots -- don't take square roots summandwise: $$5=\sqrt{25}=\sqrt{9+16}\neq3+4=7.$$

Comment: For something like the same reason the Pythagorean Theorem is $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and not $a + b = c.$